# Collectors.toMap producing wrong keys

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to have the keys of a lookup to be the keys of the final map. I have a object which performs a lookup like this

```
 dat1=org.sys.basic.DataBaseObject1
 dat2=org.sys.complex.DataComplexObject
```

These values are held in a Map obj=getLookup();

I use this map to build a final map of objects loaded from the values of the map above. However, I want the final map to have as keys the dat1 and dat2 keys and the loaded objects as values like so;

```
 dat1=..DataBaseObject1 and
 dat2=....DataComplexObject
```

Here is  my attempt.  The problem is that my final map does not have the keys dat1 and dat2 but contains the string names of the classes to load i.e org.sys.basic.DataBaseObject1. The peek shows dat1 and dat2 as keys but they don't end up as the keys in the final map.

```
Map<String, String> obj = getLookup();
Map<String, String> m = propertyNames.stream()
                                     .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), obj::getProperty));
Map<String, DataMap> handlers = handlerMap.entrySet()
                                          .stream()
                                          .peek(m -> System.out.println("Key is " + m.getKey() + " and value is "  + m.getValue()))
                                          .collect(toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> createDataMap(e.getValue())
                                          .orElse(new NullDataMapper())));
```

Comment: You can get the keys from the map.

Comment: How ?  that's what's not working

Comment: What is the type of property names?

Comment: `obj::getProperty`? What's that?

Comment: Constructor reference, Thanks anyway, I solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The correct keys were being produced. However, the Spring Framework Autowired Components were overwriting the keys in the Map, by using the Autowired component names